# Windows internet shortcuts: starting with IE maximized?

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have an internet shortcut on my desktop, with the contents looking like this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=ie&pver=6&ar=IStart
Modified=D03458CE7738C801A2
```

I was wondering if there are any tweaks I can do to guarantee that the browser starts maximized after someone loads the link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:You can't guarantee that the browser starts maximized from one special internet link. Either all or none internet links start maximized.

But: Someone had a similar problem than this.
Check [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31821712/ie7-wont-start-maximized.aspx), if it helps you.

---

Edit: owhowho I've found something really dirty, I think you shouldn't use this, but... here it is. Replace your second line with the following:

```
URL=javascript:window.moveTo(0,0);window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);window.location.href="http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=ie&pver=6&ar=IStart";
```

It doesn't make the window really maximized, but makes the browserwindow the maximum height and width.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a internet shortcut *(.url)*, create a shortcut *(.lnk)* to internet explorer. (iexplore.exe) You can set the initial windows state in lnk file. (Right-click the icon and see properties.)

You can give an URL as an argument. The target would be something like 
`"%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://reddit.com`

This is okay when you are using this only in your computer. This is not a general solution. If you want to do this programatically, there are some windows API's related to creating a shortcut. You will also have to get an path of internet explorer from the registry, as it can vary. Some users might not have IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE remembers how it was opened last time and then uses those settings.
You might find this info from Registry and use it, but I doubpt that it was implemented to get the values from startup arguments

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping quite quickly to conclusions here. I don't think you can even guarantee that Internet Explorer will start at all; you will get whatever the user set as his default browser.

Answer (score 0):

i think that it is a guarantee that the internet explorer will start unless the system is down. even if one gets the default window, from there it is very easy for you to set the browser to what you want.